# Positioning icon next to button text in ionic

Tags: css, button, ionic-framework, position, icons

I need to position checkmark icon next to the button text.
Icon is shown/hide on click event, depending if the button is clicked or not.
I managed to put it inside and show it or hide it on click but when I show it, the icon pushes button text a bit to the left. And the button text should be fixed in the middle of a button and the checkmark icon should appear in the empty space without pushing button text a bit to the left.

This is how it should look like:

[image]

And this is what I got so far:

[image]

As you can see, "02:00 AM" is pushed a bit to the left and it shouldn't be.

```
    <button ion-button [color]="i.active
        ? 'primary'
        : 'light'
      "
        block
        (click)="onToggleReminder(i)">
        <span>
          {{i.label}}
        </span>
        <ion-icon name="checkmark" float-right [hidden]="!i.active"></ion-icon>
      </button>


     .button {
        border-radius: 16px;
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: bold;
        height: 45px;
     }
     span {
        margin-right: 5px;
     }
```

Comment: have you changed the margin-right values?

Comment: @ShinoyShaji yes, that margin is there so I get a bit space in between button text and icon. Even if I remove that margin the icon pushes text a bit to the left and they are close to each other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the icon have some width by default, because of that it was pushing button text to the left. So solution is that I specified width of the icon to be 1px which is enough to place it next to button text without pushing it to the left and still making an icon visible.

```
    ion-icon {
      width: 1px;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think it obvious that this icons differ in size. Maybe try to make it smaller?

Comment: Even though this isn't a real solution, your answer helped me to find solution so I up voted your answer.